# Type error: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, undefined

I get this error on line below. How to solve this??

```
jQuery('span.facebookbtn, .fb-like-box').exists(function() {
        load('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', 'fbjssdk'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to load the data if the element exists on the page:

Jquery has no "exists" function. Instead we use ".length".

Example:

```
if (jQuery('span.facebookbtn, .fb-like-box').length)
    load('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', 'fbjssdk');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have defined `exists` function? I am not aware that it's a built in function,

Perhaps you should use `length` functuion instead:

```
if (jQuery('span.facebookbtn, .fb-like-box').length){
        load('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', 'fbjssdk'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `exists()` function in jQuery (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047/594074)), you either have to define it first (`jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}`) or use the `length` property directly for checking the existence of an element as suggested by the [jQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/).